# Cell "address" function for entire reference range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, named-ranges

The function `OFFSET($A$1:$Z$25,2,3,4,5)` refers to the range `$D$3:$H$6` of the current worksheet.

If I pass "address" as the first parameter to the `CELL` function and the above `OFFSET` function as the second parameter, I get only the address of the first cell in the range.  In other words,

```
=CELL("address",  OFFSET($A$1:$Z$25,2,3,4,5))
```

produces a value of `$D$3`.

**Is there a way to write a function to return the full reference for a range of cells?**  For example, something like:

```
=RANGE("address",  OFFSET($A$1:$Z$25,2,3,4,5))
```

that would produce a value of `$D$3:$H$6`?

**EDIT**: This is dead simple to do with a little VBA.  I was hoping to avoid that so that I would not be forced to save as a macro-enabled .xlsm file.  Here's the VBA function I'm trying to implement with worksheet functions alone:

```
Function ShowAddress(CellRange As Range) As String
    ShowAddress = CellRange.Address
End Function
```

*Note: My motivation for wanting this is to help with debugging the creation of complex dynamic named ranges.  I know that I can copy and paste the formula into the Goto box, but that adds a fair bit of work to the development cycle.*

Answer (score 0):

Cell() only returns the **first** cell in a multi-cell reference. See the [support article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf).

If you want to construct a multi-cell reference, you can use Index() for the first range and another Index for the last cell in the range. Combine the two Index functions with a : operator and the result will be a range. Note that such a formula can be used in an argument that expects a range, e.g. Sum(), or in a named formula in the name manager, but not in a worksheet cell on its own, because it returns a range.

```
=index(sheet1!$A$1:$Z$25,3,4):Index(Sheet1!$A$1:$Z$25,6,8)
```

[image]

Comment: I understand how the CELL() function works.  I'm trying to debug complex dynamic range functions and I was using the CELL() function as an example of the type of feature I was seeking.  I was hoping there would be a non-code solution but I may just have to resort to VBA.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: I showed you how to do it with the Index function. This does not require VBA. If you have all the parameters for the Offset function, you also have all the parameters for the two Index functions.